# Why are these reference types not behaving the way one would expect them to?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class called Satellite, which is meant to be a base class which I can inherit from later.
The purpose of my program is to download images from different API's on the web so I can view near-real-time satellite images.

The majority of this code is unnecessary for my question, which only references two small parts FYI.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System;

namespace satview
{
    public abstract class Satellite
    {
    protected string Path;
    protected HttpWebResponse Response;
    Bitmap LastImage;
    Bitmap Img;
    protected int ByteWidth;
    protected Rectangle Bounds;

    protected Stream ContactServer()
    {
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Path);
        Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
        return Response.GetResponseStream();
    }

    protected void Dispose(Stream DataStream)
    {
        Response.Close();
        DataStream.Dispose();
        Response.Dispose();
    }

    protected Image GetImageFromStream(Stream DataStream)
    {
        Image FinalImage = Image.FromStream(DataStream);
        Dispose(DataStream);
        return FinalImage;
    }

    public virtual Image GetLatestImage()
    {
        Image Output = GetImageFromStream(ContactServer());
        Img = (Bitmap)Output;
        return Output;
    }

    public virtual bool ImageIsDifferent()
    {
        bool Different = false;
        if (LastImage == null)
        {
            Different = true;
        }
        else
        {
            BitmapData ImgData = Img.LockBits(Bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, Img.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData LastImageData = LastImage.LockBits(Bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, Img.PixelFormat);
            unsafe
            {
                byte* ImgPtr = (byte*)ImgData.Scan0.ToPointer();
                byte* LastImagePtr = (byte*)LastImageData.Scan0.ToPointer();
                for (int Y = 0; Y < Img.Height; Y++)
                {
                    byte* ImgStartPtr = ImgPtr;
                    byte* LastImageStartPtr = LastImagePtr;
                    for (int X = 0; X < ByteWidth; X++)
                    {
                        if (*ImgPtr != *LastImagePtr)
                        {
                            Different = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        ImgPtr++;
                        LastImagePtr++;
                    }
                    if (Different)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    ImgPtr = ImgStartPtr + ImgData.Stride;
                    LastImagePtr = LastImageStartPtr + ImgData.Stride;
                }
            }
            Img.UnlockBits(ImgData);
            LastImage.UnlockBits(LastImageData);
        }
        LastImage = Img;
        return Different;
    }
    }
}
```

After I compare the two images, I then set the "LastImage" variable to the "Img" variable to prepare for the next comparison. My question is:

If I set "LastImage" to "Img", they should be referencing the same data because of the nature of reference types, correct? If this is true, why does the line "Img = (Bitmap)Output", which is executed after "LastImage = Img", not set both of the bitmaps to "(Bitmap)Output", thus always returning false in the "ImageIsDifferent" method? In practice, this code works great, but I don't understand why. I expected that I would need to clone the images so that operations on one do not affect the other.

Comment: "*The majority of this code is unnecessary for my question*" - then why are you showing it? Consider removing all irrelevant parts of your code. For your question, you have two reference variables that reference the same object. Then you assign a new object reference to one of them. Why would you expect the other to change also?

Comment: Please boil down your answer to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Needlessly lengthy code examples just get skipped because I'm not interested in looking for the needle if you're just piling extra hay on top for no reason. The problem could've been explained in 5 trivial lines of code: `var a = new Foo(); var b = new Foo(); var c = b; b = a; var whyIsThisFalse = (a == c);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I set "LastImage" to "Img", they should be referencing the same data because of the nature of reference types, correct? If this is true, why does the line "Img = (Bitmap)Output", which is executed after "LastImage = Img", not set both of the bitmaps to "(Bitmap)Output"

Reference variables contain an address location to an object on the heap. While multiple reference variables can reference the same object, they individually store their own reference. Just because you change one of the references doesn't mean the other changes.

Let's use a real world example.

- Andy lives in 742 Evergreen Terrace, Springfield.
- Bobby lives in 31 Spooner Street, Quahog.
- Cindy lives in the same house as Bobby

This is the equivalent of doing:

```
var a = new Foo();
var b = new Foo();
var c = b;
```

Now, we perform an operation:

- Bobby moves in with Andy

Which is the equivalent of

```
b = a;
```

Now, let's look at your question again, using my example:

> If I say Cindy lives with Bobby, and Bobby lives on Spooner street, then Cindy should be living in the same house as Bobby, on Spooner Street.

This part is correct.

> If Bobby now moves and lives with Andy in the house on Evergreen Terrace, why doesn't Cindy now live in that same house as Andy and Bobby?

The short answer is **because only Bobby changed his address**. No one talked about Cindy moving, so she still lives in the same house she was already known to live in, i.e. 31 Spooner Street, Quahog.

"Cindy lives in the same house as Bobby" does not mean "Cindy will always live with Bobby even if he moves". You're expecting the second, but only the first is true.

The same logic holds for the code example. Let's look at how the data changes. We start from this position:

```
HEAP
----
  001  =  "742 Evergreen Terrace, Springfield"
  002  =  "31 Spooner Streer, Quahog"

STACK
-----

  A = HEAP_001
  B = HEAP_002
  C = HEAP_002
```

This is the initial position. Now when we execute `b = a`, this (and only this) happens:

```
HEAP
----
  001  =  "742 Evergreen Terrace, Springfield"
  002  =  "31 Spooner Streer, Quahog"

STACK
-----

  A = HEAP_001
  B = HEAP_001   // Bobby now lives in Springfield
  C = HEAP_002
```

You never changed `c`, and therefore `c` still refers to the address that you set it to back when you did `c = b`, which stored the `HEAP_002` address in the `c` variable.

When you set one reference variable to equal another, these variables do not live a shared life. Any changes on the referenced object are reflected when you access it via either reference variable, but the references to the object, contained in the reference variables themselves, are unique to each reference variable. Changing one reference does not change the other.

Comment: Very helpful, but I have one more question. If I were to dispose Img after setting LastImage = Img, LastImage would also dispose right? Is this because Img.Dispose() disposes the heap memory, which by extention diposes LastImage?

Comment: @JacksonTarisa: It is because **the object itself** gets disposed, not just a particular reference to the object. The distinction is fairly easy to make, since the only thing you can do with a reference variable (as opposed to the object itself) is setting it. Any other operation, that's something you do on the object itself (and thus gets "observed" from all references to that object).